# Excel Power Query Connection and Loading into an existing Table (Query results cannot overlap a table or XML Mapping)

Tags: excel, powerquery, excel-tables

First post here.

I have an existing workbook that was created some time ago with a table by a user.  Basically the user got an extract file and simply cut and pasted the data to the table, to the right of this data are a whole bunch of formulas within the table ... so they then just copy and paste any formulas down.

What I am trying to do is remove this effort and have it refreshed from the updated extract file of raw data.

I know I could do VB to deal with this (although not done any VB for a few years), HOWEVER I notice there is a data connection and Power Query so thought this would be a better way.

Problem is as there is already a Table I can not import into it due to the said error "Query results cannot overlap a table or XML Mapping", I understand that the connection creates/recreates the table.

I have tried methods to get round this ...

1. Recreate the Table and then Find & Replace the name references, but a lot of the formulas exceed the find and replace string.
2. Tried to convert the Table to a range and then import, but I ended up with 2 two tables side by side.  I can't see anything to merge the 2 and not sure this will solve the problem when I try to import again.

Any starter for ten on this will help as I've not dabbled with Excel in this way for a few years.

Regards

Gary

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.   "...can not import into it due to the said error". What error? You did not mention any error.  What exactly are you trying to do? do you want to update an existing PowerQuery to read a different table name? Update an existing power query to output a different table? Create a new powerquery to read the table and the formula results next to it?  Please edit your question to show what you have, what you want to get to, and the issue

Comment: I have updated @horseyride

Comment: You can load an existing query to a new location by right click the query and using ... load to...   you could alternatively copy the expanded input table and range value into a new location then use that as the input table for a new query.

Comment: @horseyride but all the references are on the old location, and due to how this workbook was set up (not by myself) a lot of the formulas strings > 255 and search and replacing the references are not possible.

Comment: Sorry I can’t help here. I still have no real understanding of the issue which remains unclear

Comment: There's several answers that say using `Load To` fix that error message, <https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Power-Query/Power-Query-Data-is-updating-in-PQ-Editor-but-not-in-Excel-Table/m-p/1563716#M48452>